# Windows Events: Limit on number of enabled logs

Tags: windows, windows-10, event-log

I'm trying to collect events from multiple files (channels), including debug, analytic, diagnostics and tracing logs. When I've run a number of `wevtutil sl ... /enabled:true`, I get message: `Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.` I see no problem with the disk, RAM or the CPU.

I'm on Windows 10.

The simplest script to reproduce:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %q in (`wevtutil el`) do wevtutil sl "%q" /enabled:true
```

What's the limit?
How do I set it?
Why is it imposed?